# TFS Admin Console authorization error

Tags: security, iis, tfs

I installed an application tier just with the default settings. After the creation was finished, I get the TFS Error TF30063 (see pic) when I clicked e.g. "Group Membership". The user has admin rights on the server.
I think the IIS settings are wrong. But I don't find the right settings. Could anyone help me?

[image: TFS Error]

Comment: Could you connect to TFS from browser using the Notification URL? And in the admin console, could you see the account to open the TFS admin console listed in **[Administration Console Users](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AopgZUVNxLwJgUKT7L8q4RJbEcum)**? Are you be able to reapply your account?

Comment: Yes, I could do everything you wrote. Just 'Group Membership' and 'Administer Security' don't work.

Comment: Do you have other TFS administrators, is he able to open the 'Group membership'? What account you are using to install this TFS, a domain account or a local account?

Comment: I used a domain acc to install TFS. Other acc's don't have access either

Answer (score 0):

I would check the Internet Explorer configuration settings and the [Loopback check](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401.1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrated-authentication-and-is-hosted-on-iis-5.1-or-a-later-version).

Comment: I checked it and everything looks fine. The error still occurs